# Spinner NOT Working Well with Firestore's document.getId

Tags: java, android, firebase, spinner, google-cloud-firestore

Any idea why this doesn't work?

```
mFirestore.collection("DR1")
            .document(UserID)
            .collection("Story")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                          spinnerArray.add(String.valueOf(document.getId()));  
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

The spinner drop down works (with no default selection, just empty), but on selection, it also does not appear. No error whatsoever. I have `setOnItemSelectedListener` to `Toast.maketext` on a selection, but nothing appears as well.

But once I add a:

```
spinnerArray.add("test");
```

Before the Firestore database call (the for-loop), then everything works fine. (default selection on "test" on the dropdown list, and when I select another entry, `Toast.maketext` appears, and selection appears on the spinner)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are not defining your `spinnerArray` inside the `onComplete()` method, which has an asynchronous behaviour. To solve this, move the declaration of your `spinnerArray` inside the `onComplete()` method. To display your records you also need to set the adapter inside the method. For more information please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)**. I also recommend that you see this video, **[Asynchronous Firebase API - Cloud Firestore and Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)**, for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, I just watched thru your video. Thank you for making that. I'll work on it again later tomorrow.

Comment: Hey Alex, I just wanted to update you that I've got it working with your suggestion and work-around. Thanks much!

Comment: Happy to hear that. Cheers!