# Using Custom Objects from Cloud Firestore in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve an Events object from Firestore that I have stored and display it in an activity. I am locating the document in a document reference and then using a setEvent method to set the document (converted to an Event object) to "thisEvent" variable declared at the start.

However, when I go to set the TextViews with the information from the event, it doesn't work as thisEvent is null. I've set up an if/else to see if it is null and so everytime I run the app, the event is not displayed and instead HEY THERE is the event title as per the if statement. I have followed the Firestore documentation outlined on their website but it seems I am not going about this the correct way.

```
public class EventViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//declaring FireBase variables
private FirebaseFirestore mFStore;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

//declaring user,team and event variables
private String user_id;
private String team_id;
private String TAG = "EventViewActivity";
String event_id;
Event thisEvent;

//declaring and binding UI elements
@BindView(R.id.event_title_text) TextView event_title;
@BindView(R.id.event_date_text)TextView event_date;
@BindView(R.id.event_time_text)TextView event_time;
@BindView(R.id.event_description_text)TextView event_description;
@BindView(R.id.event_location_text)TextView event_location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_view);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    event_id = intent.getExtras().getString("event_id");
    Log.d(TAG, "eventid: " + event_id);

    //retrieve event information
    DocumentReference eventInfoRef = mFStore.collection("Teams/YfLa27NWaaQSfNwhZPgX/Events").document("MhEg0kRdJEedf7YnwvBi");
    eventInfoRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            setEvent(documentSnapshot.toObject(Event.class));
        }
    });
    if (thisEvent !=null){
    event_title.setText(this.thisEvent.getTitle());
    event_date.setText(thisEvent.getDate().toString());
    event_time.setText(thisEvent.getTime());
    event_description.setText(thisEvent.getDescription());
    event_location.setText(thisEvent.getLocation());}
    else {
        event_title.setText("HEY THERE");
    }
}

public void setEvent(Event event){
    this.thisEvent = event;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable of type `Event` as global and simply use it outside the `onSuccess()` method. This is happening because this method has an asynchronous behaviour, which means that is called even before you are getting the data from the database. A quick fix would be to use the `Event` object only inside the `onSuccess()` method or if you want to use it outside, please use the last part of my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)**. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)**.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. I figured the first part out but good to see there is another way. I'll take a look at this for future reference!