# How to get data from FireStore to custom object and then return it?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

When I run this method `returns V = null`, In consideration V inside `onComplete(...` , its `not null`

public static Vehicle v;

```
public static Vehicle tessst() {

    v = new Vehicle();

    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("vehicles").document("123");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){
               DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                if(documentSnapshot !=null){
                    v  = documentSnapshot.toObject(Vehicle.class);
                }
            }
        }
    });
      return  v;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore - object with inner Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object)

Comment: Please see the duplicate to see why your v object is null and how you can solve this using a custom callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Firestore `get()` method fetches and returns the object asynchronously which means chronologically the following occurs:

1. `return v;` statement would have executed first
2. then `get()` fetches the document details and assigns to `v  = documentSnapshot.toObject(Vehicle.class);`

So instead of returning object v using `return v;` from the method you should call a **listener** and set the object `v` after it is fetched from the Firestore.

You can also **use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html)** to send new data fetched from Firestore to your activity or fragment instead of using listeners.

```
public static Vehicle v;

// method return type changed to void
// public static Vehicle tessst() {
public static void tessst() {

    v = new Vehicle();

    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("vehicles").document("123");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                if(documentSnapshot !=null){
                    v  = documentSnapshot.toObject(Vehicle.class);

                    // TODO
                    // mListener will be called from here 
                    // or 
                    // set the value of the liveData here
                    // to send the object v obtained 

                }
            }
        }
    });
    // return v;
}
```