# How can I pass firebase data to a view class?

Tags: android, database, google-cloud-firestore, android-mvp

I using the firebase firestore to query information to load into a UI fragment. I could easily do. This call in the fragment and set the view data in the on complete listener callback. However, I don't want my view classes doing any database and network calls. The problem with doing it from a separate class is that the query call is asynchronous so I can't immediately pass the data until the listener is invoked.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the Firestore query is asynchronous, `onSuccess` and `onComplete` methods have an asynchronous behaviour.

So you can solve ths issue, using my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679). So you can call `readData()` method from within the same class or if needed, from another class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mvp pattern. it will allow to write load functions not in the Fragment class. 
The speed of loading directly depends on your network connection speed.

Comment: Well the problem is if I call from a presenter I'll get a null method return. This is because the firebase query is asynchronous