# Get the reference of the document before adding the data to collection in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling with the Firestore because there is not enough documentation which can describe all the possible working scenario of Firestore.

Let me explain my requirement.

I have the following GUI in android:

- EditText. (Name)
- Spinner. (cities)
- Spinner. (Busses)
- Add Button

The Firestore have the collections as the following:

- cities (which contain the multiple cities)
- busses (which contain the multiple busses)
- user ( which will contain the username, buss reference, city reference)

Now the problem is that when user click on the Add Button, first I have to get the reference of `selected city` and `selected bus` then add the these three values to `user` collection but to get the reference I have to call the following code.

```
final Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("username", editText.getText().toString());

        db.collection("cities")
        .whereEqualTo("name", city) // get city by name
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot query) {
                data.put("city", query.getDocuments().get(0).getReference());
                // once the city reference got, then get the Buss reference
                db.collection("busses")
                .whereEqualTo("busnumber", bus) // get bus by number
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot query) {
                        data.put("bus", query.getDocuments().get(0).getReference());
                        addData(data); // now the city and bus reference got, add the data now.
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This make the app little slow, and looks like stupid approach, I want to confirm is it the correct approach? or is there better way to do this? or in future may be I have to get the more reference then more nested calls?

**Edited**

Further more this is really stupid way that I have to recall these code again and again to get the reference of `city` or `bus` so a lot of duplication will be in my application, which is not good. So I want to create two methods `getCityRefByName(String name)` and `getBusRefByNUmber(int number)` as the following.

```
public DocumentReference getBusByNumber(int number){
    db.collection("busses")
    .whereEqualTo("busname", number)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot query) {
            query.getDocuments().get(0).getReference(); // return this reference, How?
        }
    });
}

public DocumentReference getCityRefByName(String name){
    db.collection("cities")
    .whereEqualTo("name", name)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot query) {
            query.getDocuments().get(0).getReference(); // return this reference, How?
        }
    });
}
```

The Firestore documentation is not good enough that's why I'm facing these stupid core problems.

Comment: If your requirement is that you must add data first to city collection and if its successful then only you need to add data to bus collection then your approach is good because you'll get to have track of whether the first method (citi collection) executed or not and then you may know if second method (bus collection) worked.

Comment: I'm not adding the data to city or even bus collection, I'm just getting the reference from those collections before adding the data to user collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return this reference, How?

You cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. With other words, you cannot simply use that result outside the `onSuccess()` method because it will always be `null` due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. This means that by the time you are trying to use that result outside that method, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible. A quick solve for this problem would be to use those results only inside the `onSuccess()` method, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: So my above code is fine as the get the reference of the city and then the bus reference then add to the database?

Comment: There is no problem regarding nested calls in Firestore. It's a common practice which will help you have access to the data in the upper callback. But remeber to define those lists each inside its corresponding callback.

Comment: can you elaborate `access to the data in the upper callback` and `But remeber to define those lists each inside its corresponding callback`

Comment: When you are using nested calls, one call is a parent call and the other one is a nested call. So you need to declare each list in the corresponding call. First list in the partent call and the second in the nested call. Right?

Comment: No I have to wait for all calls to get all required data before adding data in the firestore.

Comment: That's correct, this what I have explained in the post that recommened you to read. So do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes helped to confirm. I have marked as accepted, can you take a look on this similar question? which is related to messing the output due to async behavior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191349/how-to-work-with-the-reference-type-in-firestore

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run methods get City and Bus together like this

```
private boolean gotCity, gotBus;
private void run() {
    final Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("username", editText.getText().toString());
    gotBus= false;
    gotCity = false;
    db.collection("cities")
            .whereEqualTo("name", city) // get city by name
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot query) {
                    data.put("city", query.getDocuments().get(0).getReference());
                    // once the city reference got, then get the Buss reference
                    gotCity = true;
                    if(gotCity&& gotBus)  addData(data); // now the city and bus reference got, add the data now.
                }
            });
    db.collection("busses")
            .whereEqualTo("busnumber", bus) // get bus by number
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot query) {
                    data.put("bus", query.getDocuments().get(0).getReference());
                    gotBus = true;
                    if(gotCity&& gotBus)  addData(data); // now the city and bus reference got, add the data now.
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: How this approach will be fast?

Comment: The get bus process not have to wait for get city process finished, so It will be faster

Comment: I don't think so, because add data still waiting for both calls.

Comment: getCity and getBus called at one time, so addData only wait a function has longer time, not have to wait 2 functions finished.

Comment: As your code, time of process getCity is a, getBus is b, so addData have to wait a+b, but in my solution, addData have to wait a (if a>b) or b (if b> a).

Comment: I think you should use an interface to get a Callback