# I get "null" when I try to access a variable from inner class in firebase methods

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the value of a variable that's in an inner class , which was override by firebase **"addValueEventListener"** , but when I try to print out the value outside these methods I always get "NULL". This is my code:

```
DatabaseReference reff = database.getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

                    reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            User r= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                           username= r.getUserN();
```

//when I try to print out the value of username here it shows up

```
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("service").child(b);
                    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            Service s = dataSnapshot.getValue(Service.class);

                            servicename=s.getNomservice();
```

//same thing as username , i get the value

```
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    rv = new Rv(username,servicename,dt,tm);
                    RVId = myRef.push().getKey();
                    myRef.child(RVId).setValue(rv);
```

//and here when I print out username and servicename , I get null

Comment: network calls are asynchronous so take some time to complete hence the issue

Comment: thank you for answering fast , but I did not get what you said . can you please explain more.

Comment: listens will be triggered when you the response is received from network calls after some time so before that you will not have any data

Comment: but I do get a result when I add a toast inside the method "onDataChange" , but I don't get it when the toast is outside this method , I guess it has something to do with the inner class thing

Comment: refer to previous comments and in addition `rv = new Rv(username,servicename,dt,tm);` will be executed before ondatachange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use something now that hasn't been loaded yet. With other words, you cannot simply use the `username` outside the `onDataChange()` method because it will always be `null` due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. This means that by the time you are trying to print that result outside that method, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use that results only inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: yes that was the problem, and I fixed it thank you so much