# Android - Keep Listener with Firebase function out of the class

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to code my app in MVC. The problem is that I'm new in Android and I don't know how to have a `listener`/`callback` if the function is out of the main Class.

```
public void addNewUser(String firstname, String lastname, String email, Integer gender, String uid, String profileImageUrl){

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("firstname", firstname);
        data.put("lastname", lastname);
        data.put("email", email);
        data.put("gender", gender);
        data.put("boxId", "independent");
        data.put("notificationsEnabled", true);
        data.put("profileImageUrl", profileImageUrl);

        mFirebaseFirestore.collection("usersP").add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        mIRegisterActivity.inflateFragment("Register Box", mHashMap);
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });

    }
```

I would like to have this function in a different Java Class. But if I do that I don't know how to still be able to launch an action only when the function is completed execution -> in other words, when it's `addOnSuccessListener`.

Do you know how I could do that?

I'm used to coding in swift, it would be something like that:

```
func addUser(id: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
      // Code and then
      completion(user)
   }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to keep this function outside of activity class and perform operation on activity in `onSuccess()` method right?

Comment: I would like to have a class UserApi where I could have many functions like addNewUser(). And I would like to keep the listener so I can still ask mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); for example

Comment: have a look at this class. https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork/FireBaseHelper.java

Comment: You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your **own custom Listener** for that say `MyFirebaseListener` and update your things in activity by **implementing** this interface

```
public interface MyFirebaseListener {
    void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference)
    void onFailure(Exception e)
}
```

Now pass the **Activity as parameter** to `MyFirebaseListener` to `addNewUser()` method as below

```
public class UserApi{

    public void addNewUser(String firstname, 
                String lastname, 
                String email, 
                Integer gender, 
                String uid, 
                String profileImageUrl,
                MyFirebaseListener myFirebaseListener){

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("firstname", firstname);
        data.put("lastname", lastname);
        data.put("email", email);
        data.put("gender", gender);
        data.put("boxId", "independent");
        data.put("notificationsEnabled", true);
        data.put("profileImageUrl", profileImageUrl);

        mFirebaseFirestore.collection("usersP").add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        myFirebaseListener.onSuccess(documentReference)
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        myFirebaseListener.onFailure(e)
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Implement `MyFirebaseListener` interface in your Activity so you need to **override** following methods and perform your **UI modification** in those implemented methods as follows

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFirebaseListener {

    void someMethod(){
        addNewUser(firstname, 
                lastname, 
                email, 
                gender,
                uid,
                profileImageUrl,
                this) // <- This will be reference to Activity with Type of MyFirebaseListener
    }

    void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mIRegisterActivity.inflateFragment("Register Box", mHashMap);
        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
    }
    void onFailure(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
    }
}
```

This is how you can ***separate*** **UI Logic and service logic** using Custom Interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for custom Listener:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners

If you want keep listener always call,
For firebase listener, Use **application class** for listener.

If you want method global(where you need response of Firebase), Put that function Either in Application class, or Use **BroadcastReceiver** or **Listener** or **EventBus**.

Comment here if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

just add an interface ...

```
public interface IFirebaseTask {
    void OnSuccess(DocumentReference reference);
    void OnFailure(Exception e);
}
```

and then implement that interface, where it may be required to listen for:

```
public SomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements IFirebaseTask {

}
```

one can also pass the listener into constructors:

```
public SomeFirebaseTask(Context context, IFirebaseTask listener){
    this.setContext(context);
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

... into order to notify the listener defined above from elsewhere.

alternatively, one can let just any class implement the interface methods:

```
... implements OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>, OnFailureListener
```

and then bind the listener alike:

```
mFirebaseFirestore
  .collection("usersP")
  .add(data)
  .addOnSuccessListener(SomeActivity.this)
  .addOnFailureListener(SomeActivity.this);
```

the Firebase documentation (in case someone would bother to read) has this answered, as well...

see section [Detaching Callbacks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).

Answer (score 0):

First add listenerInterface

```
public interface FirebaseResponse {
     void onSuccess();
     void onFailure();
}
```

Create separate class like below

```
public class ResponseHandler implements
    OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() , OnFailureListener() {

            private FirebaseListener listener;

            public ResponseHandler(FirebaseListener listener){
                 this.listener = listener;
            }     


             @Override
             public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
              //Todo handle onSuccess
                 listener.onSuccess();
             }

             @Override
             public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //Todo handle onFailure
                 listener.onFailure();
             }
    }
```

Then add this class as response handler in your class that implements FirebaseListener

```
ResponseHandler responseHandler = new ResponseHandler(this);

mFirestore.collection("usersP").add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(responseHandler).
                .addOnFailureListener(responseHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches which you can use...
First:
U can make a callback interface just like we do in case of RecyclerView click callbacks...

Second:
U can use livedata observers if this u must have little bit idea about rxJava2, arch life or Agera....

So lets consider the first approch

Consider ur class is

```
class otherClass{
callbackInterface mCallBackInterface;

public(callbackInterface mCallBackInterface){
this.mCallBackInterface=mCallBackInterface;
}

interface callbackInterface{
void onSucuss(DocumentReference documentReference);
}


public void addNewUser(String firstname, String lastname, String email, Integer gender, String uid, String profileImageUrl){

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("firstname", firstname);
        data.put("lastname", lastname);
        data.put("email", email);
        data.put("gender", gender);
        data.put("boxId", "independent");
        data.put("notificationsEnabled", true);
        data.put("profileImageUrl", profileImageUrl);

        mFirebaseFirestore.collection("usersP").add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

mCallBackInterface.onSucuss(decumentReference);


                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });

    }

}

///The Class which will be calling it will be something like this

class CallingClass implements CallBackInterface{

@Override
void CallBackINterface(DocumentReference documentReference){

//Your code goes here
}
```

}

This will do the job broadcast receivers can also be used but above solution is best for beginners...