# Set adapter or RecyclerView refresh after Firestore function

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, realm, google-cloud-firestore

I'm populating a `realm` database table with information from a Cloud Firestore collection. On the first load, the application opens and saves the information but does not display it until I close and open the application.

I need the information to be displayed after it's been written to the realm database. ie without having to close and open the app. I tried doing this by putting them in methods and in order in the onCreate method.

So after it has written all the information to the realm database I want the recyclerview to populate but I don't know how to do that, please help?

ScreenShots

First launch(left) and second launch(right)

[image: Screen1] [image: Screen2]

OnCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_import_user);
    RelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.contentuserimport);
    // initialize realm
    Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
    //SETUP REEALM
    RealmConfiguration defaultConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .build();
    realm=Realm.getInstance(defaultConfig);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    moduleID = intent.getStringExtra("moduleID");
    moduleName = intent.getStringExtra("moduleName");
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    init();
    getAssessList();
}
```

Init():

```
private void init(){
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    friendList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    textView1.setText("Assessments - "+moduleName);
    db.collection("assessment").whereEqualTo("module","xbIpNiDXGsIPmb5sTwbH").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    //GET DATA
                    Assessment a=new Assessment(Double.parseDouble(document.get("achieved").toString()),
                            document.get("date").toString(),document.get("desc").toString(),document.get("module").toString(),
                            document.get("time").toString(),Double.parseDouble(document.get("total").toString()),document.get("type").toString(),
                            document.get("weight").toString());
                    //SAVE
                    RealmHelper helper=new RealmHelper(realm);
                    helper.save(a);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    //READ
    RealmHelper helper=new RealmHelper(realm);
    Assessment=helper.retrieve();
    //BIND
    adapter=new AssessAdapter(this,Assessment);
    friendList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    friendList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

getAssessList():

```
private void getAssessList(){        
    //RETRIEVE
    RealmHelper helper=new RealmHelper(realm);
    Assessment=helper.retrieve();
    //BIND
    adapter=new AssessAdapter(this,Assessment);
    friendList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    friendList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Can't you load the datas before to show the layout? Otherwise you can use EventBus: http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to retrieve the data outside the callback in the way you do, will not work since the `onComplete()` method has an asynchronous behavior. So you cannot simply use the following line of code:

```
Assessment=helper.retrieve();
```

And expect to retrieve and use the data like so. Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`, meaning that `onComplete()` method returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the `Task` it returns, will be called some time later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `Assessment` object you're trying to use it outside the `onComplete()` method, will not have been populated from the callback yet.

Basically, you're trying to return a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous.  That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use the `a` object that you get from the database only inside the `onComplete()` method, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion on putting it in the 'onComplete()' method