# cannot solve symbol link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I has an error in this line :   final User user = new User(Address, confirmPassword, UserEmail, Password, PhoneNumber, Username,link);

and the error is "Cannot solve symbol link"

```
private DatabaseReference Userdatabase;
private StorageReference storageReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private StorageTask mUploadTask;

private Uri imageUri;

ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Signup.this);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Seller");

    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RegisterAccount();

        }
    });

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
}

public void selectImage() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent();
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {


        imageUri = data.getData();
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri).into(imageView);

    }
}


public void RegisterAccount() {

    final String email = emailText.getText().toString();
    final String username = nameText.getText().toString();

    if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(address))) {
        addressText.setError("address is required");
        addressText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    AddUser(email, username, pass, phone, comfirmpass, address);

}

public void AddUser(final String UserEmail, final String Username, final String Password,
                    final String PhoneNumber, final String confirmPassword, final String Address) {

    String email = UserEmail.replace(".", ",");

    Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(email);


    Userdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                Log.i(TAG, "UserEmail : " + value + " Had Already Exist");

                Toasty.warning(getApplicationContext(), "The Email you use already Exist !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                return;
            }


            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (imageUri != null) {
                  final  StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));



                    mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUri) {
                                            String link = downloadUri.toString();
                                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Register successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            final User user = new User(Address, confirmPassword, UserEmail, Password, PhoneNumber, Username,
                                                    link);
                                            Userdatabase.setValue(user);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            return;
        }
    });

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Buyer FirebaseAuth Register : Fail");
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "The Email you use already Exist !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Buyer FirebaseAuth Register : Success");
                UserEmail.replace(".", ",");
                final User user = new User(Address, confirmPassword, UserEmail, Password, PhoneNumber, Username,link);
                Userdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Userdatabase.setValue(user);
                            Log.i(TAG, "FirebaseDatabase Add Buyer : Success");
                            Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), "Register Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                            }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Database Error");
                        }
                        });
                }
                }
                });
}
```

I had removed some of the codes if you need more details pls leave a comment below.  Anyone can help with this? your help is much appreciated

[image]

Comment: Your `link` object is a valid object of type String. Can please add a screenshot of your error, to see how it looks like?

Comment: i added an image, is that what you request?

Comment: you never declare Link

Comment: i got declare String link = downloadUri.toString(); in addsuccesslistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare link at the start of your class with the other variables, and then set link when you need it. It can't resolve symbol link because it doesn't exist in the context youre calling it.

```
private DatabaseReference Userdatabase;
private StorageReference storageReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private String link;

private StorageTask mUploadTask;

private Uri imageUri;

ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Signup.this);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Seller");

    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RegisterAccount();

        }
    });

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
}

public void selectImage() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent();
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {


        imageUri = data.getData();
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri).into(imageView);

    }
}


public void RegisterAccount() {

    final String email = emailText.getText().toString();
    final String username = nameText.getText().toString();

    if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(address))) {
        addressText.setError("address is required");
        addressText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    AddUser(email, username, pass, phone, comfirmpass, address);

}

public void AddUser(final String UserEmail, final String Username, final String Password,
                    final String PhoneNumber, final String confirmPassword, final String Address) {

    String email = UserEmail.replace(".", ",");

    Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(email);


    Userdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                Log.i(TAG, "UserEmail : " + value + " Had Already Exist");

                Toasty.warning(getApplicationContext(), "The Email you use already Exist !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                return;
            }


            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (imageUri != null) {
                  final  StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));



                    mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUri) {
                                            link = downloadUri.toString();
                                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Register successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            final User user = new User(Address, confirmPassword, UserEmail, Password, PhoneNumber, Username,
                                                    link);
                                            Userdatabase.setValue(user);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            return;
        }
    });

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Buyer FirebaseAuth Register : Fail");
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "The Email you use already Exist !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Buyer FirebaseAuth Register : Success");
                UserEmail.replace(".", ",");
                final User user = new User(Address, confirmPassword, UserEmail, Password, PhoneNumber, Username,link);
                Userdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Userdatabase.setValue(user);
                            Log.i(TAG, "FirebaseDatabase Add Buyer : Success");
                            Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), "Register Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                            }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Database Error");
                        }
                        });
                }
                }
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error, because the declaration of your:

```
String link = downloadUri.toString();
```

Is out of the scope. You cannot simply use the String `link` declared in `addsuccesslistener`, in your `onComplete()` method because is a total different scope. The String `link` can **only** be see,n in the scope where it have been declared. Beside that, both methods have an asynchronous behavior. So even if you make that variable, a global variable, it won't solve the problem. The simplest fix I can see, would be to use in your `onComplete()` method, the `link` as an empty String:

```
final User user = new User(
    Address,
    confirmPassword,
    UserEmail,
    Password,
    PhoneNumber,
    Username,
    "" //empty String
);
```

And update accordingly, when you get it.

See also **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** more informations.

Comment: Hi Choy! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?