# Doucment.getString not giving an output (Firestore)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I just wrote a basic code to get multiple documents from Firestore database. The task is getting successful and you could see the `document.getId()` & `document.getData()` value in Log, but after that when I use `document.getString()`, it gives a blank output. I have been trying to find my error but I am unable to and I have a project submission due tomorrow. Ignore all the textview declaration in the given code below:

```
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
private int month,year;
private Calendar calendar;
private  String email;
private String name,points;
private int i,j;
private String q,p,r;
public String[][] data= new String[10][10];
private TextView rankingTextView,a,b;
public TextView t01,t02,t03,t10,t11,t12,t20,t21,t22,t30,t31,t32,t40,t41,t42,t50,t51,t52,t60,t61,t62,t70,t71,t72,t80,t81,t82,t90,t91,t92;

private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);
    calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    t01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t00);
    t02=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t01);
    t03=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t02);
    t10=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t10);
    t11=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t11);
    t12=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t12);
    t20=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t20);
    t21=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t21);
    t22=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t22);
    t30=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t30);
    t31=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t31);
    t32=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t32);
    t40=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t40);
    t41=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t41);
    t42=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t42);
    t50=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t50);
    t51=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t51);
    t52=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t52);
    t60=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t60);
    t61=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t61);
    t62=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t62);
    t70=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t70);
    t71=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t71);
    t72=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t72);
    t80=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t80);
    t81=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t81);
    t82=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t82);
    db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    month = month + 1;
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    i=0;
    j=0;
    dothis();
    Toast.makeText(this, "MO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    t01.setText(data[0][0]);
    t02.setText(data[0][1]);
    t11.setText(data[1][0]);
    t12.setText(data[1][1]);
    t21.setText(data[2][0]);
    t22.setText(data[2][1]);
    t31.setText(data[3][0]);
    t32.setText(data[3][1]);
    t41.setText(data[4][0]);
    t42.setText(data[4][1]);
    t51.setText(data[5][0]);
    t52.setText(data[5][1]);
    }
private void dothis()
{i=0;
j=0;

    db.collection("users")
           // .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("points" + Integer.toString(month) + Integer.toString(year), "0")
            .orderBy("points" + Integer.toString(month) + Integer.toString(year)).limit(10)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            if(document.exists()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData() + " ");
                                data[i][j] = document.getString("username");
                                data[i][j + 1] = document.getString("points" + Integer.toString(month) + Integer.toString(year));
                                i++;
                                Toast.makeText(Leaderboard.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

}

Please don't duplicate my question. I searched a lot before putting.

Comment: Null means there is no field with the name you're looking for.

Comment: I wouldnt say null I would say blank value ...its not giving anything

Comment: Please add your database structure and please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Done!.

Comment: So you are saying that `document.getString("username")` inside `onComplete()` method is returning nothing? Or `data[i][j]` is returnin nothing outside the `onComplete()` method?

Comment: @AlexMamo when I toast document.getString("username"), the username gets printed but its data[i][j] isn't receiving any value inside onComplete() method .Even when I set a random text to a TextView inside the onComplete() method it doesn't get displayed.

Comment: `data[i][j]` is not printing even if you are assigning `document.getString("username")` to it?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes!.

Comment: In which place of your code are you trying to print `data[i][j]` and it isn't printing anythig?

Comment: @AlexMamo I am setting the text of the textviews to data[i][j]

Comment: And in which place of your code are you trying to print `data[i][j]` because I cannot see this.

Comment: @AlexMamo  t01.setText(data[0][0]); .. here

Comment: I understand. I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you say that when are you calling the following line of code:

```
t01.setText(data[0][0]);
```

Nothing is set to your `t01` TextView and this is the normal behaviour since the data that is coming from the Firebase database is asynchronous. This means that the `onComplete()` method returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the `Task` it returns, will be called some time later.

There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because this method returns immediately, the value of your `data[0][0]` variable you're trying to use outside the `onComplete()` method, will not have been populated from the callback yet.

Basically, you're trying to use a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be set all those texts to your TextViews only inside the `onComplete()` method. If you need to set them outside, I recommend dive into the asynchronous worlds and see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)** for a better understanding.