# Android Firestore db returns value exact every seccond time

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

i have  a real strange problem. I have two methods where i parse data depending on user selected values. In my seccond method i parse those data. The seccond method returns always the right values but in my first method gets this values only every seccond time. I cannot find the issue. The list which i get from previous method is also right, so i get also all values.
Here is my Code:

```
      mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Suche", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                ArrayList<String> selectedCategories = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < mUserItems.size(); i++) {

                    selectedCategories.add(listItems[mUserItems.get(i)]);


                }
              //  selectedCategories.add("asdf");
            getStores(selectedCategories);
            }
        });

     private void getStores(ArrayList<String> checkedItems) {

        for (int i =0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++){
        String checkedItem = checkedItems.get(i);
        getStore(checkedItem);
    }
    getDistanceToUser(sellers2);
}

    private void getStore(String checkedItem) {
        db.collection("Seller")
                .whereEqualTo("typ", checkedItem)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                SellerObject so = document.toObject(SellerObject.class);
                                so.setId(document.getId());
                                sellers2.add(so);

                                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: toa"+sellers.size());
                            }



                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: It's because all database queries are asynchronous and return immediately, before the data is available.  But you're expecting the data in `sellers2` to be available immediately after calling getStore().

Comment: and how can i solve this issue?

Comment: because i need the whole result for the following methods

Comment: The easiest thing is to only deal with the results of the query inside the callback for the query itself, and not anywhere outside the callback.  Unless you ensure that other location is only invoked after the callback is done.

Comment: You can also check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** out.

Comment: thanks i solved it by following @Doug Stevenson instructions