# How can I filter documents in Firestore based on an array stored in another collection?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database organized like so:

[FirestoreDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7C6R.png)
[image: FireStore DB]

I have three fragments which display: all posts, posts of individuals that user is following and all the posts by the user. My issue is with getting the posts of individuals that user is following to work, the other two work.

I previously have tried to get the array from Firestore and use that array to query the posts of followed users but I am unable to access the array outside of the method that generates it as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Like so:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("following").document(currentUser.getUid());
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        List<String> group = (List<String>) document.get("following");
                    } else {
                    }
                } else {
                }
            }
        });

Query posts = db.collection("posts").whereEqualTo("userId", group);//Does not compile since cannot resolve group.
```

Where I then created an array using the `DocumentSnapshot` however since my query is outside the scope of the method I cannot use the created array.

What I currently have that does not work is the following:

```
Query posts = db.collection("posts").whereEqualTo("userId", FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("following")
                .document(currentUser.getUid()));
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

final Issue

```
private void readData(MyCallback callback){
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("following").document(currentUser.getUid());
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())){
                        String group = document.getString("following");
                        followingList.add(group);
                    }
                    callback.onCallback(followingList);//says must be declared final
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Please also edit your question to add the code the produces: "I am unable to access the array outside of the method".

Comment: Is that better? I can add the code of the working fragments if necessary.

Comment: Why do you say "I am unable to access the array outside of the method"? How do you that?

Comment: Since the array is created inside the method it cannot be accessed outside of it.

Comment: I edited the code for clarity.

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two main issues in your code. The first one would be at the following line of code:

```
Query posts = db.collection("posts").whereEqualTo("userId", group);
```

The `group` object is not in the scope where it is defined, so that's why you have a compilation error. Beside that, there is no way you can pass to the `whereEqualTo()` method, as the second argument a list. If you want to create a new query for each user in your array, you should iterate over it and pass as the second argument a String.

Second issue is that `onComplete()` has an asynchronous behaviour. Even if you have created the list as a global variable, it won't work since that method returns immediately and the value of your `group` list you're trying to use it outside the `onDataChange()` method, will not have been populated from the callback yet.

A quick solve for this problem would be to move the above line of code inside the `onComplete()` method and pass a String and **not** a list, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much the video provided was exactly what I needed.

Comment: One last issue though, I have edited the question above to explain.

Comment: Then declare it as final, if this is what you need.

Comment: That gives me the error: ```addOnCompleteListener
(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>)
in Task cannot be applied
to
(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot>)
 ```

Comment: And if I change from QuerySnapshot to DocumentSnapshot it tells me:```foreach not applicable to type 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot'```

Comment: The fact that you are getting another error, sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. In order to follow the rules of this community, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.