# How Should I fetch the document fields and use them in another map for another collection?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How should I fetch the document fields from one collection and combine them to add a new document to another collection? I have attached [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqtBV.png) of the database how does it looks, I want to fetch the fields from the collection show and want to update it to the new collection along with some other data:

```
private void savePost(String mPostTitle, String mPostContent, String mlistSpinnerC) {
        final DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(mauth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null) {
                        String username = (String) 
document.get("username");
String email= (String) document.get(email);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

        postMap.put(Constants.POSTTTITLE, mPostTitle);
        postMap.put(Constants.POSTCATEGORY, mlistSpinnerC);
        postMap.put(Constants.POSTCONTENT, mPostContent);
        postMap.put(Constants.TIMESTAMP, (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000));
        postMap.put(Constants.USER_ID,mauth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        postMap.put("username", username);


        PostsRef.document().set(postMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Intent toHomeActivity = new Intent(AddPostActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(toHomeActivity);
                }

            }
        });
```

I am just not able to map the fields from one collection to another collection, please guide me the correct method to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you are trying to add the `username` to your `postMap` using the following line of code:

```
postMap.put("username", username);
```

The data has not finished loading yet from the database and this is because the listener you have added to your `get()` call is being invoked some unknown amount of time later after your query finishes. You don't know how long it's going to take, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. The `onComplete()` method has an asynchronous behavior, that's why you cannot get that `username` in such a way.

A quick solve for this problem would be to move all that block of code related to adding data  to the `postMap`, inside the `onComplete()` method. In this you are waiting for the callback and `username` your will be available. Otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Can I use firestore transactions in this case? if so, guide me for that as well. Thank You

Comment: You should use transactions only when you need to know a value before you change it. Please also note that a transaction absolutely requires round trip communications with server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully. So in your case, to simply read a document, there is no need to use transactions.