# How to get Uri value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have copied the value of the String `photolink` in another string `PhotoLink1` but this show value only in `URI` method but not out side the Method, I don't how to get the value or is there anything I miss. Please tell me how to get this value or how should i make this code worked. I searched lot of questions about this but I can't get the solution .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.setup_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Account Setup");
        circleImageView=(CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        n=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_txt_up);
        s=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save_set_button);
        s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String user = n.getText().toString().trim();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(user) && imageURI!=null)
                {
                    String user_id= firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                     StorageReference img_path = storageReference.child("profile_image").child(user_id+ ".jpg");
                    img_path.putFile(imageURI).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Task<Uri> task_uri = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
                                task_uri.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        String photoLink = uri.toString();
                                        getImageUri(photoLink);
                                        Toast.makeText(Setup_Activity.this, ""+photoLink, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Log.d("photLink", ""+PhotoLink1);
                                    }
                                });

                                Map<String,String > userMap= new HashMap<>();
                                userMap.put("name",user);
                                userMap.put("image", PhotoLink1);
                                firestore.collection("Users").document().set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(Setup_Activity.this, "This is  good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            String err= task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(Setup_Activity.this, "Error "+err, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String err= task.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(Setup_Activity.this, "Error "+err, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Setup_Activity.this, "Empty Text Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        circleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                {
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Setup_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Setup_Activity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Setup_Activity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        getImage();


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    getImage();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void getImageUri(String photoLink) {
        PhotoLink1 =photoLink;
    }

    public void getImage(){
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .start(Setup_Activity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               imageURI = result.getUri();
               circleImageView.setImageURI(imageURI);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you are trying to add those values to your `userMap` using the following lines of code:

```
Map<String,String > userMap = new HashMap<>();
userMap.put("name",user);
userMap.put("image", PhotoLink1);
```

The `photoLink` has not finished loading yet from the Firebase Storage and this is because the listener you have added to your `task_uri` object is being invoked some unknown amount of time later after your task finishes. You don't know how long it's going to take, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that `photoLink` is actually available. The `onSuccess()` method has an asynchronous behavior, that's why you cannot get that `photoLink` in such a way.

A quick solve for this problem would be to move all that block of code related to adding data  to the `userMap`, inside the `onSuccess()` method. In this you are waiting for the callback and `photoLink` your will be available. Otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks buddy!! The same idea is clicked in my mind after posting the question , you describe here . Thanks for your response.

Comment: Done Buddy! Check it. Have a nice day