# How to return the value given by the gps within a function

Tags: java, android

I am trying to return the result value that gives me the sum of latitude and longitude, but the function is giving me back the default value

```
Double result = 0.1;

public Double codeQR(final Context context, final Activity activity){

    client2 = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    client2.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            result = (latitude +longitude);

        }

    });


   return result;
}
```

I expected the result of the sum of latitude and longitude, but it is returning 0.1

Comment: What result did you expect exactly ?

Comment: Is GPS / Location permission set? Are you sure that your LocationClient is working (receiving the current location)?

Comment: the result of the sum of latitude and longitude, but it returns the initial value that is 0.1.

Comment: the GPS is working, it is giving me the latitude and longitude data, but the function returns me before the default value of "result"

Comment: `onSuccess` is asynchronous and so result will always have the initial value.

Comment: I understand that it is asynchronous, but how could I implement a solution for this case?

Comment: You should create a callback to handle the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Andy said, the OnSuccessListener is asynchronous, so it will runs on a different Thread while your return value is on the main Thread.

You have different workaround :

Workaround 1) Declare in your scope a global result variable, that you can reuse anywhere in your class after you set it with your OnSuccessListener :

```
private Double result;
```

Workaround 2) Pass it to a method directly in its parameter :

```
public void codeQR(final Context context, final Activity activity){

    client2 = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    client2.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            result = (latitude +longitude);

            anotherMethod(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Workaround 3) Create a callback Interface, put this callback in your method parameter, and then call your method wherever you need to access the "result" value :

```
 //A) Create a callback Interface
 public interface MyCallback {
    void onCallback(Double result);
}

//B) Put this callback in your method parameter
public void codeQR(final Context context, final Activity activity, MyCallback myCallback){

    client2 = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    client2.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            result = (latitude +longitude);

            myCallback.onCallback(result);
            }
        });
    }

    //C) Call your method wherever you need to access the "result" value
    //For example, if you want to get the result value in the nextStep() method
    private void nextStep(){
       codeQR(this, this, new MyCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onCallback(Double result) {
                    Log.i("TestOfResult", "onCallback: " + result);
                }
          });
     }
```

You can find more explanations about this interface on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method).
I hope this will help you, let us know if this worked or if you have questions !