# how to get the document id of a document that has a field with a specific value?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get the document id of a document which has a field that has a specific value for example in this collection, i would like to retrieve the document id of the document where the "itemName" is "eggroll.[image: firestore collection]

Comment: This sort of simple query is covered in the documentation, I suggest reading it over if you are going to use Firestore for more queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, please try the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference deliveryRef = rootRef.collection("delivery");
Query nameQuery = deliveryRef.whereEqualTo("itemName", "eggroll");
nameQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getId());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output in your logcat will be the following document id:

```
8jy6 ... fcrm
```

Comment: i need to use the document id out side the oncomplete function though. I'm not  very familiar with the Query object

Comment: You need to use a custom callback. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** out.

Comment: th callback example is a void. i want to store the data in a string. any examples?

Comment: There is no way you can do that. You should use that in an asynchronous manner as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a simple query like the one mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries).

Execute it. And the document.getId() which will give you the ID of the document matching the query criteria.