# How do I decide on a view of a fragment of a navigation drawer depending on a boolean variable?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I'm learning Android for myself and now I'm using a Navigation Drawer to interact with a part of my application. What I want is when I choose the `questionItem` from the `NavigationActivity` I want to return a `View` depending on a boolean variable stored in the Firebase Firestore. I know that queries on Firebase are asynchronous and that's why the no_question layout is returned always, even if the value of the variable stored is true. But I don't know how to solve it, and I will be really grateful if someone help me to find a solution. I've tried lots of solutions like using threads to synchronize or sleeping the main thread but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment {

    private View root;

    private boolean[] question_act = new boolean[1];

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        isQuestion_act(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void activacioRebuda(final boolean qNova) {
                question_act[0] = qNova;
            }
        });

        if (question_act[0]) root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
        else root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noquestion, container, false);

        return root;
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void activacioRebuda(final boolean question);
    }

    private void isQuestion_act(Callback callback) {

            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            assert user != null;
            String id = user.getUid();

            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            db.collection("players")
                    .whereEqualTo("Id", id).whereEqualTo("Question_act", true)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                boolean q = document.getBoolean("Question_act");
                                Log.d(TAG, " question " + q);
                                if (callback != null) {
                                    callback.activacioRebuda(q);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assigning `question_act[0] = qNova;` doesn't make any difference. As you already mentioned in your question, Firebase API is asynchronous, so using the value of `qNova` outside the callback will **never** work.

The only option that you have is to wait for the data by using the value of `qNova` only inside the `activacioRebuda()` method, as you are pretty sure that the operation of getting the data from the database is 100% complete.

For a working solution, please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to return a DocumentSnapShot as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679)

Comment: Alex, thank you for your answer, but it's not solving at all my problem. How can I update the variable "root", that is a View, inside activacioRebuda() and return then in the onCreateView?

Comment: My answer did not solve all the problems, right? But the first one is solved, right?

Comment: Besides that, that's a totally different question. If you have a hard time with the second issue, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.