# How to structure code when there are too many events android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore and learning Android. The problem I am facing is about structuring the code. Following is my use case:

1. The user wants to add a new note, inputs note's title
2. I want to check if any other note with the same title exists
3. If yes, then don't allow, else create

Earlier it was easy with SQLite. I could just run a query to get data in a list, check the list and act accordingly.

```
// BEFORE
private boolean fnValidate() {
    // some code...

    // run Sqlite query and get data in a list or something

    // check if exists, return accordingly
}

// NOW
private boolean fnValidate() {
    // some code...

    notesRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot s : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            // add data to list or something
        }

        // 'exists logic' will go here??

    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        // show error
    });

    // I want 'exists logic' here like it was earlier so that I can properly return true/false
}
```

Now as you can see, this won't work in a sequential manner. It will start the task to get notes and will proceed. Therefore, I need to add my `exists logic` in `OnSuccessListener`.

Furthermore, in the future, if I have to check for some other value before my `exists logic`, I would again have to move `exists logic` inside that condition's `OnSuccessListener` and so on.

Also, from where to return the value true/false to original caller `fnValidate`?

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but I am very confused about how the ideal structure should be. Please tell me what are the best practices here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore, I need to add my exists logic in `OnSuccessListener`.

Yes, when `onSuccess()` fires, it means that you are 100% sure that the operation of getting the data from the database is 100% successful and you can use that data as needed. You always need to wait for the data.

> Furthermore, in the future, if I have to check for some other value before my exists logic, I would again have to move exists logic inside that condition's OnSuccessListener and so on.

Yes, that the way asynchronous programming works.

> Also, from where to return the value true/false to original caller `fnValidate`?

There is no way you can return the data (`fnValidate`) as a result of a method. For a working solution, please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to return a DocumentSnapShot as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679)

Comment: FYI, I was expecting you or Doug to answer, because you are the guys who have answered similar questions. And thanks for the explanation. I have already read your answer and fixed the code according to async paradigm. `Yes, that the way asynchronous programming works - but at first, it sucks`

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work. Yes, at first glance is as you say but you'll get used to it :)