# Saving documents from firestore into room database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-room

I have an activity where there are multiple `recyclerViews` where I populate them with data from my `firestore` database.

The code below is used to read the data from `firestore` and add it into the recyclerView (I also check there if users reported the items to remove them but it is not important for the question).

```
private void ShowNew(Boolean isGBS) {
    db.collection( "Items" ).orderBy( "DateCreated", Query.Direction.DESCENDING ).limit( AppConstants.Item_TO_LOAD ).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener( queryDocumentSnapshots -> {

                List<DiscoverItems> Items = new ArrayList<>();

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    reportsNew = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (document.get( "Reports" ) != null) {
                        reportsNew = (List<String>) document.get( "Reports" );
                        if (reportsNew.size() > AppConstants.ALLOWED_REPORTS) {
                            PopUps popUps = new PopUps();
                            popUps.deleteReported( document.getString( "ItemID" ) );
                        } else {
                            Items.add( new DiscoverItems( document.getString( "ItemID" ) ) );
                        }
                    } else {
                        Items.add( new DiscoverItems( document.getString( "ItemID" ) ) );
                    }

                }

                List<DiscoverItems> finalItems = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> ItemsID = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++) {
                    finalItems.add( new DiscoverItems( Items.get( i ).getItemID() ) );
                    ItemsID.add(Items.get( I ).getItemID() );
                }

                saveToDB(ItemsID);

                discoverItemAdapter = new DiscoverItemAdapter( finalItems, listener );
                rv_NewItems.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration( 0 );
                rv_NewItems.setAdapter( discoverItemAdapter );

            } );

}
```

Now, I had like to save the list of `ItemsID` into a room database in order to use it later for loading the `recycerlView` to save calls from kfirestore.

In order to do so, I wrote this code:

```
private void saveToDB(List<String> s) {
    class saveToDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        public saveToDB(List<String> s) {
            super();

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            //creating a task
            ItemId itemId = new ItemId();
            String itemsList = ItemId.ListToString( s );
            itemId.setItemId( itemsList );

            //adding to database
            ItemIdClient.getInstance( getApplicationContext() ).getItemDB()
                    .itemIdDao()
                    .insert( itemId );
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute( aVoid );
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }

    saveToDB s2db = new saveToDB(s);
    s2db.execute();
}
```

Now, my problem is that where it calls `saveToDB` it calls on an empty List. From my understanding, it is because firestore is an async task.

I tested the code of saveToDB() by saving a list that was created within the method and it works good so the problem is that it does not get any list to save when it is written as above.

How can I call saveToDB() so it will obtain the ItemsID list full with items and not an empty list?

From my understanding, it means to call saveToDB after firestore has finished its task but I don't know how to implement it.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Ben. Any code that needs data from Firestore, needs to be inside the onSuccess() method, or be called from there. Besides that, The Firestoree client already runs all network operations in a background thread. This means that all operations take place without blocking your main thread. Putting it in an AsyncTask does not give any additional benefits. Indeed, the Firebase API is asynchronous, so please check my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679)**.

Comment: @AlexMamo, thank you for the answer. Correct me if im erong but thats what I did. I put saveToDB() inside the onSuccess of firebase. The problem I faced is that it seems like it started saveToDB before I had results from firestore which resulted in saving empty lists. It didnt block my thread.

Comment: Yes, and this is because of the asynchronous Firebase API.