# How can i wait until the onsuccess listener has a result in Kotlin

Tags: android, database, firebase, kotlin

I have this code

```
val collectionDb = db.collection(collection)
                .add(user4)
                .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                    Log.d("SUCCESS", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
                    println(documentReference.id)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.w("FAIL", "Error adding document", e)
                }

                //here wait

                println("more code")

    }
```

The output is first `more code` and later the `DocumentReference.id`

But I want that on `//here wait` the script pause until there is a success or a fail.

I'm new so it would be very nice when you can help me out.

Comment: You might also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want that on //here wait the script pause until there is a
> success or a fail.

That would be impossible. That's the point of an asynchronous operation - it will complete, whether it succeeds or fails, at a *later* point in time and when that time will be, we can't really be sure. I have a Q&A here if you want more information on how to handle these types of functions:
[Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

but your best bet would be to add all the relevant code inside your `addOnSuccessListener` listener, because this is where you know that the request has completed and it succeeded

Answer (score 2):

When you want to execute script after success or failure just create a method and call it from success or failure callback as below.Please check if below is useful.

```
 val collectionDb = db.collection(collection)
            .add(user4)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                Log.d("SUCCESS", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
                println(documentReference.id)
                doRequiredOperation("Success")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w("FAIL", "Error adding document", e)
                doRequiredOperation("failuire")
            }


fun doRequiredOperation(msg:String){
    if(msg.equals("Success"){
        println("more code"). //It will execute after success callback 
    }
}
```