# for loop inside OnSuccessListener not working in Firestore query

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The for loop inside the OnSuccessListener not running.

The app is getting crashed when the setNextQuestion() function is added inside the onCreate function.

Whenever the setNextQuestion() function is being called the QuizActivity crashes and returns back to the HomeFragment.

QuizActivity.java

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityQuizBinding binding;

    ArrayList<Question> questions;
    int index = 0;
    FirebaseFirestore database;
    Question question;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityQuizBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        questions = new ArrayList<>();
        database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        SharedPreferences getShared = getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String catId = getShared.getString("catId","CmYfZdAGsDpA2Vupktb4");
        final String topicId = getIntent().getStringExtra("topicId");

        database.collection("categories")
                .document(catId)
                .collection(topicId)
                .orderBy("index")
                .limit(5).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Question question = snapshot.toObject(Question.class);
                    questions.add(question);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void setNextQuestion() {
            question = questions.get(index);
            binding.question.setText(question.getQuestion());
            binding.option1.setText(question.getOption1());
            binding.option2.setText(question.getOption2());
            binding.option3.setText(question.getOption3());
            binding.option4.setText(question.getOption4());
        }
    }
```

Database Inspector

> Error reading Sqlite database: Database 'LiveSqliteDatabaseId(path=/data/data/com.example.quizly/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db, name=google_app_measurement_local.db, connectionId=1) not found

Logcat when `setNextQuestion()` is being called

```
2021-05-27 13:41:27.100 16962-16962/com.riteshknayak.masterq E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.riteshknayak.masterq, PID: 16962
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.riteshknayak.masterq/com.riteshknayak.masterq.QuizActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2022)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7147)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.riteshknayak.masterq.QuizActivity.setNextQuestion(QuizActivity.java:55)
        at com.riteshknayak.masterq.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7272)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7263)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2022) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7147) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

Comment: did you check if `queryDocumentSnapshots` has items

Comment: If your app crashes, there's going to be an error message and stack trace in its logcat output. Please find those and add them to your question, with the edit link that is right under it.

Comment: I have tried hardcoding the categoryid and topicid there are currently 7 documents inside each topic collection

Comment: @frankvanpuffelen no error in logcat but a massage from the database inspector

Comment: App's QuizActivity Crashes only and goes backs to the HomeFragment

Comment: If the app crashes, there is indeed a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo  added to the question

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Because by the time you are calling:

```
question = questions.get(index);
```

Your "questions" list is empty, hence that error. This is happening because Firebase API is asynchronous. So any code that needs data from the database, needs to be inside the onSuccess() method, or be called from there. So the simplest solution would be to call `setNextQuestion()` right from the onSuccess() method.

For more info please also see my answer from the following post:

- [How to return a DocumentSnapShot as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679)

Comment: If you try to use `Log.d("TAG", question.getQuestion().toString());`, is there  something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: Those are some errors related to authentication and not to reading the data from Firestore. So you should debug your app, get rid of those errors, and then the read operation should succeed.

Comment: The authentication errors should be considered other questions. So if you have hart time solving them, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Comment: I noticed something unusual Please checkout ttps://drive.google.com/file/d/12q3rWnVIFUoOls2LJ3XaFMqUIzpxwgeJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RITESHNAYAK I think you should send that to the Firebase team.

Comment: yeah , I DId it 7 hours ago

Comment: can you also answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/67790042/14017441