# How to run a set of code once previous line is completed?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have tried debugging each line of below code. After reaching `.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot ->` in  `database.collection("users")`  section. The code  `database.collection("categories")` and the next code is being executed until the end than  `r[0] = Integer.parseInt(documentSnapshot.getString("LastQuestion")));` code of the `database.collection("users")`   section is Excuted.

I want that  `r[0] = Integer.parseInt(documentSnapshot.getString("LastQuestion")));`first executed so that `.whereGreaterThan("index", r[0])` shuld not runned with `r[0]` being `null`

```
final Integer[] r = new Integer[1];
        r[0] = 1;
        database.collection("users")
                .document("0mu8LcLm8aREn14Qa13LvxTJv9D3")//TODO user hardcoded
                .collection(catId)
                .document(topicId)
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot ->
                r[0] = Integer.parseInt(documentSnapshot.getString("LastQuestion")));

        database.collection("categories")
                .document(catId)
                .collection(topicId)
                .orderBy("index", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .whereGreaterThan("index", r[0])
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Question question = snapshot.toObject(Question.class);
                question.setUId(snapshot.getId());
                questions.add(question);
            }
            setNextQuestion();
        });
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do is what you're doing now--include it in the callback. There are many ways to handle asynchronous code; you're already doing one of them.

Comment: @Davenewton I don't understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you would have to make the second query in the Success listener:

```java
database.collection("users")
    */ ... */
    .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(documentSnapshot.getString("LastQuestion")));
        database.collection("categories")
                /* ... */
                .whereGreaterThan("index", a)
                /* ... */
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        /* ... */
                    }
                }
}
```