# Firestore | SnapshotListener returned object cannot be used

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My current problem is that I need to get a document, but I have to make sure that if it's updated or modified in any way I can have them reflect it on my side.

Thanks in advance.

Main Activity:

```
        Anime anime;
        Review review;
        // gets all reviews that the current user has done
        db.collection("reviews").whereEqualTo("usuarioID", usuario.getUID()).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                reviewsList.clear();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : querySnapshot) {

                    review = doc.toObject(Review.class);
                    review.setUID(doc.getId());
                    // this gets the anime from firestore and maps it to a class.
                    db.collection("animes").document(review.getAnimeID()).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value,
                                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                            // this returns an anime with all it's attributes correctly.
                            anime = value.toObject(Anime.class);
                            anime.setUID(value.getId());
                            // I set the anime of the review previously obtained here.
                            review.setAnime(anime);
                        }
                    });
                    review.setUsuario(usuario);
                    // review is added but anime keeps returning null.
                    reviewsList.add(review);
                }
                Log.e("Lista reviews usuario: ", reviewsList.toString());
                reviewAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(reviewsList, function);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(reviewAdapter);
            }
        });
```

My Review class:

```
        public class Review implements Serializable {
            private String UID;
            private String titulo;
            private String comentario;
            private int rating;
            private Anime anime;
            private String animeID;
            private Usuario usuario;
            private String usuarioID;
            private Integer likes;
            private Integer dislikes;

//getters and setters
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo It's more of a logical problem, my 'anime' variable gets the data from Firestore but when I try to use review.setAnime(anime), that variable is suddenly null as If I haven't declarated it or didn't get the data from firestore.

Comment: What is the value of `anime` right after you get it from Firestore?

Comment: @AlexMamo I set it with the value.toObject(Anime.class) and returns an object with all attributes, not null.

Comment: Have you tried to move `review.setUsuario(usuario);` and `reviewsList.add(review);` right after `review.setAnime(anime);`? Does it work this way?

Comment: @AlexMamo I did as you said and the reviewList has a size of 0. But debugging tells me it should have been added to the list. It is really weird.

Comment: It's most likely because of this [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679). If you understand Kotlin, this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will also help.

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm going to take a look at that solution, thank you very much for your patience!