# Return action being performed before the firestore update OnCompleteListener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, return-value

I have two files one named firebaseDatabase which is a non-activity class for handling the functions of the database. A function called firestoreCreateUser takes the details of the user and updates them in the firestore database and returns a boolean value according to the action performed.

```
public class FirebaseDatabase {
public boolean initUserResult;

public boolean firestoreSetupUser(String userUID, String phone_number, String live_address, String want_address) {
    DocumentReference userSetupRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("users")
            .document(userUID);

    Map<String, Object> user_new_data = new HashMap<>();
    user_new_data.put("phoneNumber",phone_number);
    user_new_data.put("homeLocation", live_address);
    user_new_data.put("rentalLocation", want_address);

    userSetupRef.update(user_new_data)
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
            });
    return initUserResult;
}
```

The other file takes the boolean value and starts another activity.

```
 public boolean setupUserResult;
 exploreClick.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        phone_number = phoneNumberInput.getText().toString();
        current_location = currentLocationInput.getText().toString();
        want_home_location = wantHomeLocationInput.getText().toString();
        setupUserResult = setupUserObj.firestoreSetupUser(getUid, phone_number, current_location, want_home_location);

        if(setupUserResult){
            startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeUser.this, HomeScreenActivity.class));
        }
        else{
            recreate();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Setup User Failed : ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is when the function updates details the function returns first and then the OnCompleteListener is executed, even if the database is updated it returns false.

Comment: Firebase API is asynchronous, so I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679) might help. If you understand Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will also help.

Comment: @AlexMamo I used your resources to modify my code but still, the same problem arises.

Comment: Without seeing what you have done, it's hard to say why the problem arises. Maybe you should add another question here, on StackOverflow, in which you should explain what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I just added an answer. Have a look below.

Comment: Any code that needs data from the database, needs to be inside the onComplete method, or be called from there. The same rule applies also in the case of a custom callback. You cannot return the `initializeUserResult` object as a result of a method.