# Cannot retrieve field from a document in Firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

My app tries to retrieve the value of a field in a document in Firebase.

The structure of the `Firebase` database is very simple: The root `collection` is called "Users". It contains a single `document`, called "vfS6yOAJsjR49eWcXOeIvZCulJl2" (i.e. the `userID` automatically generated by Firebase). This document contains a single field, which is called "stockList". This field contains a `JSON String` (all verified through `Firebase Console`).

The code I'm using to retrieve the value of the field "stockList" is:

```
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private DocumentReference documentRef;  
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseUser currentUser;
private String json; 

 auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
 Log.d(TAG, "UserID: "+ currentUser.getUid() );

 if(currentUser != null){
    documentRef = db.collection("Users").document(currentUser.getUid());
    documentRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
         Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: OK");
         json = documentSnapshot.getString("stockList");
    }
                     .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
         Log.d(TAG, "Download Failure" );
    }
 }
```

The Logcat always says **"Download Failure"** (`json` remains indeed empty), though the user is properly authenticated by Firebase (`currentUser.getUid() == "vfS6yOAJsjR49eWcXOeIvZCulJl2"`).

My `Firebase security rules` are:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /Users/{userID} {
      allow read, write : if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
  }  
}
```

Your advice is much appreciated.

*PS: I'm test-running the app through the Emulator in Android Studio. So internet connectivity shouldn't be the cause.*

Comment: Log the error, e, in the failure listener and see what error firestore is throwing. From there we can now know what is the problem from the error's code

Comment: Have you tried in your code `documentRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {` as in [this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48499310/17544309)

Comment: Have you tried to use `Log.d(TAG, "Download Failure: " + e.exception!!.message!!);`? Do you get something printed out? Please respond with @AlexMamo