# Method that checks if a firestore document is a specific type of document

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Android Studio project with 2 user collections: trainers and trainees. I want to make a method that receives the user's string email as input (the user's email is the document ID in both collections and a user can be either in the trainees collection or in the trainers collection not in both) and the method returns a boolean containing true if the user is a trainer and false if he isn't (meaning he is a trainee).

This is the code I came up with but its not working, it returns false all the time even if the user is a trainer. Am I doing something wrong? is there a better way to do this?

```
public static boolean isTrainer(String email)
{
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference trainerRef = firestore.collection("trainers").document(email);
    DocumentReference traineeRef = firestore.collection("trainees").document(email);
    // Check if the trainer document exists
    Task<DocumentSnapshot> trainerTask = trainerRef.get();
    boolean isTrainer = trainerTask.isSuccessful() && trainerTask.getResult().exists();
    // Check if the trainee document exists
    Task<DocumentSnapshot> traineeTask = traineeRef.get();
    boolean isTrainee = traineeTask.isSuccessful() && traineeTask.getResult().exists();
    // If the trainer document exists but the trainee document doesn't, the user is a trainer
    Log.d("FirestoreExample", "isTrainer: " + isTrainer + ", isTrainee: " + isTrainee);
    return isTrainer && !isTrainee;
}
```

I tried many things but nothing worked

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that you might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know ahead of time if a user is a trainer or a trainee, then you have to explicitly check that. As I see in your code, you have two different collections, `trainers` and `trainees`. Which in your case, doesn't help much, because you have to perform two different checks.

So in your case, I would recommend a schema with a single collection that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- users (collection)
     |
     --- $email (document)
           |
           --- type: "trainee"
           |
           --- //other user fields
```

To check if a user is a trainer or a trainee, you only have to create a reference that points to the user document, read the document, and check the type of the user like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection("users");
DocumentReference emailRef = usersRef.document(email);
emailRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                String type = document.getString("type");
                if(type.equals("trainer")) {
                    //Do something.
                } else {
                    //Do something else.
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

When you call [DocumentReference#get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#get()), the type of object that is returned is a `Task<DocumentSnapshot>`. So in order to get the result, you have to attach a listener, which is an asynchronous operation There is no way you can make that operation synchronous. This means that you cannot return the result of an asynchronous operation as a result of the method. For more information, I recommend you read my answer in the following post:

- [How to return a DocumentSnapShot as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679)

Comment: Hey Raz. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?